# Why is there sometimes a discrepency between Font Size and SelectionFont Size?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I have a project with a `RichTextBox` in which I am trying to calculate differences in font sizes. I was seeing some strange numbers that I would not expect, so I made an incredibly simple test app.

What I'm trying to do is get the font size of the first character and the font size of set to the `RichTextBox` itself and display it in a `Label` using the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    richTextBox1.Text = "This is a test";
    //richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, 8.5f);

    label1.Text = richTextBox1.Font.SizeInPoints.ToString();

    richTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
    label2.Text = richTextBox1.SelectionFont.SizeInPoints.ToString();
}
```

Now, this is great and all (default size is 8.25), but if I uncomment the line in that block to increase the font size to 8.5, my labels read 8.5 (label1) and 8.25 (label2). I'm not sure where this difference comes from. If I change to 8.6, the selection is still 8.25. But if I change to 8.7, the `SelectionFont.SizeInPoints` returns 9. Setting to something like 18.4, I get 18.75 for the selected...

Now I'm sure there's some method to the madness, it's just not clear to me, and is making it hard to calculate real differences in font size, since in my test app I should *ideally* be getting 0 between the first character and `richTextBox1.Font.SizeInPoints`.